# viewWillLayoutSubviews not called MKMapView placed on storyboard with autolayout turned off

Tags: swift, autolayout, ios9, xcode7, ios-autolayout

I noticed sometimes, viewWillLayoutSubview does not get called.

1) A blank storyboard + Autolayout turned ON -> will be called

2) A blank storyboard + Autolayout turned OFF -> will be called

3) A blank storyboard + a mapview + Autolayout turned ON -> will be called

4) A blank storyboard + a mapview + Autolayout turned OFF -> will not be called

Isn't this strange? It looks like I am forced to use autolayout when I have a mapview on the storyboard. Why?

Comment: I am experiencing an issue that may be related: It only fails on iOS 9.3 (on iOS 6, 7, 8, 9.2 it works fine). If ViewController has a reference to a MKMapKit, viewWillLayoutSubviews is called every time. If VC has a reference to a custom UIView, and that custom UIView holds a MKMapView then it fails on this scenario: launch VC (viewWillLayoutSubviews is called), try to rotate the map (so that north gets rotated), viewWillLayoutSubviews is called again. Pop VC (to go back to previous VC). Then if I re-launch our VC with custom UIView that holds the map, viewWillLayoutSubviews is NOT called

Comment: In case anyone ends up here as I did: I had a similar issue with a view structure: ViewController->custom_UIView->MKMapView. viewWillLayoutSubviews is not called sometimes only on iOS 9.3 (iOS 6.0-9.2 it works fine). It seems that adding a MKMapView to VC root view on loadView solves the issue: [self.view addSubview:[[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero]]; Hope this helps!

Comment: hi alex, I kind of accidentally solve it using your method too: programatically create the MKMapview instead of placing it on my xib.